# Find and remove objects in an array based on a key value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have been trying several approaches on how to find an object in an array, where ID = var, and if found, remove the object from the array and return the new array of objects.

**Data:**

```
[
    {"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"},
    {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
    {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
]
```

I'm able to search the array using jQuery $grep;

```
var id = 88;

var result = $.grep(data, function(e){
     return e.id == id;
});
```

But how can I delete the entire object when id ==  88, and return data like the following?

**Data:**

```
[
    {"id":"99", "name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
    {"id":"108", "name":"You are awesome!"}
]
```

Comment: What about using `slice` function and a little `for` loop?

Comment: Sure, but, reason I wrote this question, is because I am stuck ;)  any snippets?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827894/how-do-i-slice-an-array-from-an-array-of-object-literals

Comment: The title and question text seem to conflict... suggesting two entirely different approaches: **A.** remove items from an array versus  **B.** create a new, filtered array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove array element based on object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

> I can grep the array for the id, but how can I delete the entire object where id == 88

Simply filter by the opposite predicate:

```
var data = $.grep(data, function(e){ 
     return e.id != id; 
});
```

Comment: This answer provides the most concise and idiomatic solution for jQuery

Comment: In you case where you want to delete all items with id=something is fine ... but be careful when using $.grep as it searches the full array and for long arrays it is not efficient. Sometimes you just need to check if the element exists inside the array by a given ID, then is better to use another iteration method ;)

Comment: This doesn't remove that object from list

Comment: @ArunSivan Yes, it overwrites the `data` variable with a new list, which is usually a much better idea.

Comment: What if he intended to remove the object from list, so that he can use the new array some where else..like `myArray.slice(index,1);`

Comment: @ArunSivan `slice` doesn't remove anything either. Not sure what you're getting at. If you have a specific problem yourself, you might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Bergi Hi. If I have an array of ids and I want to remove them then what should I be doing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Learner Filter for the array to not [contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the respective id.

Comment: @Bergi Extremely Sorry but I didn't get you. Instead of a single id = 88, if I have an array like id = [88, 99] then how can I remove those 2 objects and get only "{"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}" in the data.

Comment: @Learner `data.filter(e => !ids.includes(e.id))`

Answer (score 303):

Here is a solution if you are not using jQuery:

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
  return obj.id !== id;
});
```

Comment: Is this better than doing `findIndex()` and then `splice(index, 1)` on parent array?

Comment: splice mutates the originating array. With filter you have the choice.

Comment: You can reduce this to a single line by using: myArr = myArray.filter(obj => obj.id !== id);

Comment: even more concise `arr = arr.filter( obj => obj.id !== id);`

Comment: Can someone explain about time complexity difference between ' filter() ' and ' findIndex()+splice(index,1) '

Answer (score 107):

You can simplify this, and there isn't really any need for using jQuery here.

```
var id = 88;

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].id == id) {
        data.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Just iterate through the list, find the matching id, splice, and then break to exit your loop.

Comment: +1, but you should mention that this does delete only the first item which matches.

Comment: ... And if you need to delete each matched items, loop on reverse order with `i=data.length; i > 0; i--` and don't use `break`.

Comment: `i = data.length` will break any `data[i]`, it should be something like `i=data.length -1 ; i > -1; i--`

Answer (score 43):

There's a new method to do this in [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015)/2015 using findIndex and the array spread operator:

```
const index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id === id);
const newData = [
    ...data.slice(0, index),
    ...data.slice(index + 1)
]
```

You can turn it into a function for later reuse like this:

```
function remove(array, key, value) {
    const index = array.findIndex(obj => obj[key] === value);
    return index >= 0 ? [
        ...array.slice(0, index),
        ...array.slice(index + 1)
    ] : array;
}
```

This way, you can remove items by different keys using one method (and if there's no object that meets the criteria, you get original array returned):

```
const newData = remove(data, "id", "88");
const newData2 = remove(data, "name", "You are awesome!");
```

Or you can put it on your Array.prototype:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function (key, value) {
    const index = this.findIndex(obj => obj[key] === value);
    return index >= 0 ? [
        ...this.slice(0, index),
        ...this.slice(index + 1)
    ] : this;
};
```

And use it this way:

```
const newData = data.remove("id", "88");
const newData2 = data.remove("name", "You are awesome!");
```

Comment: findIndex() is really great! 

Comment: What if you have more than one key and value?

Answer (score 14):

Native [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) solution:

```
const pos = data.findIndex(el => el.id === ID_TO_REMOVE);
if (pos >= 0)
    data.splice(pos, 1);
```

If you know that the element is in the array for sure:

```
data.splice(data.findIndex(el => el.id === ID_TO_REMOVE), 1);
```

Prototype:

```
Array.prototype.removeByProp = function(prop,val) {
    const pos = this.findIndex(x => x[prop] === val);
    if (pos >= 0)
        return this.splice(pos, 1);
};

// usage:
ar.removeByProp('id', ID_TO_REMOVE);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oriadam/72kgprw5/

Note: this removes the item in-place. If you need a new array, use `filter` as mentioned in previous answers.

Comment: You do not handle the case where the id is not found. In this case, your solution remove the element of the array

Comment: these is very clean

Answer (score 12):

```
var items = [
  {"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"},
  {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
  {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
];
```

If you are using jQuery, use [jQuery.grep](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep) like this:

```
items = $.grep(items, function(item) { 
  return item.id !== '88';
});
// items => [{ id: "99" }, { id: "108" }]
```

Using ES5 [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
items = items.filter(function(item) { 
  return item.id !== '88'; 
});
// items => [{ id: "99" }, { id: "108" }]
```

Comment: Noooooo! Do not use `jQuery` map as a filter.

Comment: Agree! Your solution with grep is the right solution with jQuery.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that ids are unique and you'll only have to remove the one element `splice` should do the trick:

```
var data = [
  {"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"},
  {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
  {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
],
id = 88;

console.table(data);

$.each(data, function(i, el){
  if (this.id == id){
    data.splice(i, 1);
  }
});

console.table(data);
```

Comment: You have the elements in your callback function backwards. It should be `each(data,function(idx,ele)`. I'll bill you later for the 30 min I wasted figuring that out :)

Comment: Oops. The least I can do in that case is update my answer. I feel really bad about your wasted 30 minutes of life.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the previous answers. A simple way if you want to find an object by id and remove it is simply like the below code:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var newObj = obj.filter(item => item.Id != 88);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const data = [
    {"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"},
    {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
    {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
];
```

Here we get the index of the object whose value of the id is "88"

```
const index = data.findIndex(item => item.id === "88");
console.log(index); // 0
```

We use splice function to remove the specified object from data array

```
data.splice(index,1);
console.log(data); // [{"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},{"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are looking for `$.grep()` function:

```
arr = [
  {"id":"88","name":"Lets go testing"},
  {"id":"99","name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
  {"id":"108","name":"You are awesome!"}
];

id = 88;
arr = $.grep(arr, function(data, index) {
   return data.id != id
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Array.prototype.removeAt = function(id) {
    for (var item in this) {
        if (this[item].id == id) {
            this.splice(item, 1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This should do the trick, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeUG4/)

Answer (score 3):

[`sift`](https://github.com/crcn/sift.js/tree/master) is a powerful collection filter for operations like this and much more advanced ones. It works client side in the browser or server side in [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js).

```
var collection = [
    {"id":"88",  "name":"Lets go testing"},
    {"id":"99",  "name":"Have fun boys and girls"},
    {"id":"108", "name":"You are awesome!"}
];
var sifted = sift({id: {$not: 88}}, collection);
```

It supports filters like `$in`, `$nin`, `$exists`, `$gte`, `$gt`, `$lte`, `$lt`, `$eq`, `$ne`, `$mod`, `$all`, `$and`, `$or`, `$nor`, `$not`, `$size`, `$type`, and `$regex`, and strives to be API-compatible with [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) collection filtering.

Comment: Why no upwotes? If this thing is properly writen and have no terrible bugs it should beextremely usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you coerce the object id to an integer if you test for strict equality:

```
var result = $.grep(data, function(e, i) { 
  return +e.id !== id;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d64Dt/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js), it is easy to remove an object based on a key.

Example:

```
  var temp1=[{id:1,name:"safeer"},  // Temporary array
             {id:2,name:"jon"},
             {id:3,name:"James"},
             {id:4,name:"deepak"},
             {id:5,name:"ajmal"}];

  var id = _.pluck(temp1,'id'); // Get id array from temp1
  var ids=[2,5,10];             // ids to be removed
  var bool_ids=[];
  _.each(ids,function(val){
     bool_ids[val]=true;
  });
  _.filter(temp1,function(val){
     return !bool_ids[val.id];
  });
```