# Empty an array when function triggered

Tags: javascript

```
var names = {};

// PUTTING DATA TO tmpChatters output example is.

[ { name: 'aaa', age: '', sex: 'man'},
  { name: 'bbb', age: '', sex: 'female'} ]


function deleteFunction(currentName) {

}
deleteFunction('aaa');
```

So `deleteFunction` must empty where names eqauls the name inside the object.
How do i need to do this ?

Comment: So you don't want to EMPTY the array, you want to delete the object where `name` is `aaa`, correct?

Comment: can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript find and remove object in array based on key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659888/javascript-find-and-remove-object-in-array-based-on-key-value)

Comment: So you are deleting a single object from an array of objects based on the value contained in an arbitrary field in the the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as a `forEach();`

```
   names.forEach(function(a, b){
        if(curretNick === a.name){
            names.splice(b, 1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over it and slice the object out of the array:

```
for(var i = yourArray.length; i--;){
    if(yourArray[i].name === currentName){
        yourArray.splice(i,1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Should give you what you want. If there can be multiple names that match, just remove the `break` to loop over them all.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `yourArray = yourArray.slice(i,1);`?

Comment: This make the whole object empty

Comment: @inna - i messed up, this should have been `splice` instead of `slice` ... i had a typo originally and it cascaded. oh well, the OP got the answer they wanted.