# Unable to delete from dictionary in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dictionary object in jQuery that contains data like this:

```
var category = [];
var brand = [];
var parameter = [];

category = $("input:checkbox[name=category]:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();

brand = $("input[type='radio']:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();

parameter.push({
    brand: brand,
    category: category,
});
```

Then I tried to remove the key and value pair from parameter dictonary like this but nothing got removed:

```
var brand = "something"
delete parameter.brand
console.log(parameter)
```

the parameter dictionary looks like this

```
Array[2]
0: Object
brand: Array[1]
0: "spykar"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
category: Array[1]
0: "Men Jeans"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
1: Object
brand: Array[1]
0: "Madame"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
category: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

**edit**

As per Zamuka told me i tried to filter the array like this

```
$table.on('click', '.remove', function() {
              var brand = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').prev('td').html();
              console.log(brand)
              $(this).closest('tr').remove();
              parameter = parameter.filter(isItemOk);

              function isItemOk(item) {
               return item.brand != brand;
             }

            console.log(parameter)
        });
```

How can I delete a particular brand and corresponding categories from the parameter dictionary which contains more than one key value pairs of brand and categories?

Comment: `delete parameter[0].brand`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript find and remove object in array based on key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659888/javascript-find-and-remove-object-in-array-based-on-key-value)

Comment: parameter[0] deletes only the first one...i have multiple key value pairs of brand and categories@RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

describe what items you want to keep and filter your array

```
// if brand is string
function isItemOk(item) {
    return item.brand != 'something';
}

parameter = parameter.filter(isItemOk);
```

or

```
// if brand is array _that contains_ a string
function isItemOk(item) {
    return item.brand.indexOf('something')==-1;
}
```

or same code a bit shorter :

```
parameter = parameter.filter((item)=>item.brand!='something');
```

Comment: ahh.. forgot that jquery gives you not an array but array-like object. Use .map( someFunctionHere ).toArray()

Comment: See, everything should be fine with parameter variable cause its an array you've made. 

I've missed that your brand property is also an array (why for if its a radio button). whatever.. just be creative with isItemOk function.


    function isItemOk(item) {
        return item.brand.indexOf('something')>-1;
    }


PS:  to make a fine string from an object avoiding __proto__ stuff -  use JSON.stringify(parameter, null, 4);

Comment: yeah actually i wrote that brand thing by mistake...it shudnt be an array

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove an item from array, first of all, you should get the index of this element. Then you can call `delete`, but it actually will replace array element with `undefined`. To completely remove an element, use splice:

```
var arr = ['qwe', 'rty']
var i = arr.indexOf('qwe')
arr.splice(i, 1); //['qwe']
console.log(arr); //['rty']
```

---

UPDATE

You can't delete from hash by value. You should find the key corresponding to value:

```
parameter = { brand: 'SomeBrand', category: 'Any' }
var brand = "SomeBrand"

for (var key in parameter) {
  if (parameter.hasOwnProperty(key) && parameter[key] === brand) {
    delete parameter[key]
  }
}

console.log(parameter); //Object {category: "Any"}
```

Comment: But the brand array is part of parameter dict ..what i want here is to delete the corresponding brand and category from parameter dict

Comment: it doesnt enter inside the if condition i tried console.log(parameter[key]) then it prints Object {brand: Array[1], category: Array[1]}

Comment: Could you paste an example of your `parameter`?

Comment: parameter included in the question@Alex Todef