# Filterring an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to do a check if one of the objects in the Array has the id of 2 if so remove that object. `list.filter(e => e.id === 2)` returns`[ { name: 'bread', id: 2 } ]` which is the part i want to remove but if i check if it is in the array by doing `if(list.indexOf(list.filter(e => e.id === 2)) != -1)` it returns -1 saying its not in the list. Any help would be apreciated!

```
var list = new Array();
list.push({name: 'apple', id: 1})
list.push({name: 'bread', id: 2})
console.log(list.filter(e => e.id === 2));
console.log(list);
if(list.indexOf(list.filter(e => e.id === 2)) != -1) {
    list.splice(list.indexOf(list.filter(e => e.name === 2)));
    console.log(list);
} else {
    console.log('The id of 2 has not been found');
}
```

Comment: You can't compare arrays like that; arrays are objects and JavaScript comparison objects only compare objects by identity. Use `.find()` or `.findIndex()` instead of `.indexOf()`

Comment: ```list = list.filter(e => e.id !== 2)```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript find and remove object in array based on key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659888/javascript-find-and-remove-object-in-array-based-on-key-value)

Comment: As purely a comment of observation (not insult nor condescension), I find it interesting that you recognize the behavior is the exact opposite of what you intended and that you did not think to switch up the operator to mirror your intention.

Comment: Botnet, I just realised that to :p. Stupid of me to not think of that

Comment: Not stupid, but I found it humorous - thx! :)  Regarding your `indexOf` you can compare for the equality of operators without some custom solution to look into the sameness of the keys and values.  More than likely you just want to check the length of the filtered result to see if you found any matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just use `!==` instead `===`.

But you can use `find` method.

```
var elem = list.find(e => e.id === 2);
if(elem)
   list = list.filter(e => e.id !== 2);
else
   console.log('The id of 2 has not been found');
```

Comment: This was wat I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You are using filter, like it *filters out* elements, while it actually *keeps elements that fit the condition*. Change your condition to `e.id !== 2` and it keeps all elements with *ids not equal to 2*:

```js
var list = new Array();
list.push({name: 'apple', id: 1})
list.push({name: 'bread', id: 2})
list.push({name: 'milk', id: 3})
list.push({name: 'butter', id: 4})

console.log(list.filter(e => e.id !== 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert the logic of the `filter` predicate function.

```
list.filter(e => e.id !== 2);
```

`filter` returns only the items that match the predicate - in your case it will return a list of only one element which has the ID of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with `indexOf` you're searching for an array with the element that you've found.

`filter` returns an array with the results. You should use `find` instead which returns a single element:

```js
var list = new Array();
list.push({name: 'apple', id: 1})
list.push({name: 'bread', id: 2})

var index = list.indexOf(list.find(e => e.id === 2));
var result = index !== -1;

console.log('index', index);
console.log('result', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use list.filter(e => e.name === 2). It will return an **array** include the object , not the object itself. So it will return -1. You can use the spread syntax to extract the object out of the array contain it:

```
list.indexOf(...list.filter(e => e.id === 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` won't work as you will be searching for an object and object comparison in JavaScript is tricky (a custom evaluater is needed to check sameness).  The good news is you may not need it.

As noted in comments and elsewhere, filter was behaving opposite to what you desired.  Changing the comparison operator from `===` to `!==` is one way to solve that issue.

In the code below, I've included some other goodies you may find value, such as:

- the `Array.of()`
- shorthand property names (e.g., `{ foo } === {'foo': foo}`)
- series execution using the comma operator (i.e. `,`) especially to avoid curly-braces
- `...` as a rest operator for function arguments
- and others

```js
let search_id = 2;             // id to filter out

let list = Array.of(
 {name: 'apple',  id: 1},
 {name: 'bread',  id: 2},
 {name: 'orange', id: 3},
 {name: 'bagel',  id: 4}
)
log({list});


let filtered = list.filter(e => e.id !== search_id)
log({filtered});


if (filtered.length)
  log(`Found ${filtered.length} matches!`);
else
  log(`The id of ${search_id} has not been found`);




// Simple logger so label is on its own line
function log(){
  let [param1,...args]=arguments;
  
  switch (typeof param1){
    case 'string': 
      if (args.length)
        console.log(`${param1}:`),  // comma intentional
        console.log(args.pop())
      else
        console.log(param1);
      break;
    case 'object':
      for (let key in param1)
        console.log(`${key}:`),   // comma intentional
        console.log(param1[key])
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Error in passed arguments.  Type not recognized.')
  }      
}
```