# Delete multiple objects in an array by id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a main array of objects with each object having some key/values as well as a "id" key with 1,2,3,4,5, etc
Now I have another array representing just id's (like [2,3])

I want to use this array to delete objects from the main array...so in this case, objects from the main array having id's 2 & 3 should be deleted

While I am aware of findBy(id), I am not sure if that can be used to delete multiple objects at once.

Comment: run a loop on the second array and then delete then matching elements from the first array

Comment: Do you want to **delete** items from the original array or to get a new filtered one?

Comment: You haven't found anything that would give a direction on where to go? Like [Remove all elements contained in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957348/remove-all-elements-contained-in-another-array) or [javascript find and remove object in array based on key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659888/javascript-find-and-remove-object-in-array-based-on-key-value) or ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove array element based on object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `filter`. In the filter callback function check if the `id` is also there in `id` array by using `includes`

```js
let idArr = [1, 2]
let obj = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'abc'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'abc'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'abc'
  }
];

let data = obj.filter(item => !idArr.includes(item.id));
console.log(data);
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks...So, it affects the original array...Correct

Comment: @testndtv no it does not affect main array

Comment: What if we want to force that...i.e. the original array to be affected...

Answer (score 2):

using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) might work well here. you could write something like:

```js
var newArray = oldArray.filter(object => !ids.includes(object.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, like this:

```js
[2,3].forEach(key => {
    delete object[key];
})
```

Comment: This removes by index, not by id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter method for this.
Ex:

```js
let id = 2;
let list = [{
  Id: 1,
  Name: 'a'
}, {
  Id: 2,
  Name: 'b'
}, {
  Id: 3,
  Name: 'c'
}];
let lists = list.filter(x => {
  return x.Id != id;
})
console.log(lists);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to **delete** items from the original array by entirely removing the element from the array (and you don't want to get a **new array**), you can take advantage of 
[Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
let idArr = [1, 2];
let obj = [{
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4
  }
];

for (let id of idArr) {
  // look for the element by its id.
  const objIdRef = obj.find(i => i.id === id);
  // if it actually exists, splice it.
  objIdRef && obj.splice(obj.indexOf(objIdRef), 1);
}
console.log(obj);
```

If the obj array is big, you might want to make a map from it before processing the id array, so that the complexing is reduced to O(1) when the delete process begins.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps This is what you want:

```js
var arr= [{id:1, name: "foo"}, {id:2, name: "bar"}, {id:3, name:"not to be deleted"}];

var idsToDelete = [1, 2];

var res = arr.map((i, idx)=>{
   return arr[idx] = idsToDelete.includes(i.id)? undefined : arr[idx]
}).filter(i=>i)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Lodash.js functions _.forEach() and _.remove()

```js
let valuesArr = [
    {id: 1, name: "dog"}, 
    {id: 2, name: "cat"}, 
    {id: 3, name: "rat"}, 
    {id: 4, name: "bat"},
    {id: 5, name: "pig"},
]; 
let removeValFromIndex = [
    {id: 2, name: "cat"}, 
    {id: 5, name: "pig"},
]; 
_.forEach(removeValFromIndex, (indi) => {
    _.remove(valuesArr, (item) => {
        return item.id === indi.id;
    });
})

console.log(valuesArr)
/*[
    {id: 1, name: "dog"},  
    {id: 3, name: "rat"}, 
    {id: 4, name: "bat"},
]; */
```

Don't forget to clone (_.clone(valuesArr) or [...valuesArr]) before mutate your array