# How to exclude certain property from the list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm having the below list and I would like to add only these **property names** `PRODUCT_TYPE`, `PRODUCT_TERM`, `PRODUCT_ID` in `myProduct`. I want to ignore rest of the properties - I've around 100 properties and want to filter only a few of them from `myProduct`

**Please find my code below:**

```js
const obj = {
  myProduct: [
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_PRICE",
      value: "234.324",
    },

    {
      name: "PRODUCT_NAME",
      value: "Insurance",
    },
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_TYPE",
      value: "Life",
    },
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_TERM",
      value: "Long",
    },
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_ID",
      value: "AP3232343JKD",
    },
    {
      name: "PRODUCT_ENABLED",
      value: "TRUE",
    },
  ],
};

const allowedNames = [
  'PRODUCT_TYPE',
  'PRODUCT_TERM',
  'PRODUCT_ID'
];

const updateCertainProperties = {
  PRODUCT_ID: "app.productID",
  PRODUCT_ENABLED: "app.product.enabled"
};

const productName = "testProduct_3234dfasfdk3msldf23";
const environment = obj.myProduct.map((o) => {
  obj.myProduct.filter(product => allowedNames.includes(product.name));
  if (updateCertainProperties[o.name]) o.name = updateCertainProperties[o.name];
  if (o.name === "PRODUCT_NAME") o.value = productName;    
  return obj.myProduct;
});

console.log(obj.myProduct)
```

**Expected output:**

```js
[
  { name: 'PRODUCT_NAME', value: 'testProduct_3234dfasfdk3msldf23' },
  { name: 'PRODUCT_TYPE', value: 'Life' },
  { name: 'PRODUCT_TERM', value: 'Long' },
  { name: 'app.productID', value: 'AP3232343JKD' },
  { name: 'app.product.enabled', value: 'TRUE' }
]
```

Can someone please help me how can I achieve this? Appreciated your help in advance!

Comment: Many duplicated answers for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659888/javascript-find-and-remove-object-in-array-based-on-key-value

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of allowed names and `filter` them out using [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

*css just for prettier output*

***UPDATE***
added `updateCertainProperties` object values into `allowedNames` array and moved `filter` outside `environment` map.

```js
const obj = {
    myProduct: [
        {
            name: "PRODUCT_PRICE",
            value: "234.324",
        },

        {
            name: "PRODUCT_NAME",
            value: "Insurance",
        },
        {
            name: "PRODUCT_TYPE",
            value: "Life",
        },
        {
            name: "PRODUCT_TERM",
            value: "Long",
        },
        {
            name: "PRODUCT_ID",
            value: "AP3232343JKD",
        },
        {
            name: "PRODUCT_ENABLED",
            value: "TRUE",
        },
    ],
};

const allowedNames = [
    'PRODUCT_TYPE',
    'PRODUCT_TERM',
    'PRODUCT_NAME'
];

const updateCertainProperties = {
    PRODUCT_ID: "app.productID",
    PRODUCT_ENABLED: "app.product.enabled"
};

allowedNames.push(...Object.values(updateCertainProperties));

const productName = "testProduct_3234dfasfdk3msldf23";

const environment = obj.myProduct.map((o) => {
    if (updateCertainProperties[o.name]) o.name = updateCertainProperties[o.name];
    if (o.name === "PRODUCT_NAME") o.value = productName;
    return obj.myProduct;
});

obj.myProduct = obj.myProduct.filter(product => allowedNames.includes(product.name));

console.log(obj.myProduct)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: unset !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ciekals11. Your answer looks good - I forgot to update a few scenarios in my original post. Dynamically I'm changing few property names for example PRODUCT_ID -> app.productID and other use case is changing the value of the PRODUCT_NAME. I've updated the code in my original post, on top of that I want to include your filter logic but something is going wrong there -could pls help me with your filter logic in my existing use case. Appreciated!

Comment: @MikeMarsh I have updated my answer. Had to add just one line after `updateCertainProperties` object declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing *filtering an array*, not "excluding properties".  You have an array of objects, with each object consisting of a `name` property and `value` property.  And you only want objects with specific values in their `name` property.

[Using `.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the array, it might look something like this:

```
obj.myProduct = obj.myProduct.filter(p => (
  p.name === 'PRODUCT_TYPE' ||
  p.name === 'PRODUCT_TERM' ||
  p.name === 'PRODUCT_ID'));
```

This would filter out all elements of the array which don't match the supplied condition.